# Error "setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated" when trying to export signed package for Android app

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, processing

I am a beginner to programming and I just finished a simple game for Android made using Processing. However, when I try to get the app's APK (to export signed package) I get the following errors:

The keystore could not be created, due to the following error:

Build folder: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\android5125294986448583924sketch
The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.

As I am a beginner I have absolutely no clue how to proceed.

It would really suck to see all the effort that I put into creating the app to go to waste....

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first thing you should do is try googling the error message. I get a ton of results for googling `The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.`. What do those links tell you to do?

Comment: Most of them such as this one https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2216 discuss code that I have nowhere in my sketch and may not even be in java (have only used processing IDE so far), I have absolutely no clue where I can find and edit a file with this code .... furthermore NOWHERE do they properly explain where to find a gradle in my SDK and what a gradle even is so I can start working toward fixing the issue...

Answer (score 11):

Look at each warning in turn:

```
The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
```

This is telling you that something is being deprecated. The next line give you a hint why.

```
Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
```

Note that the method has changed name *and* the method argument has changed from type "File" to type "FileCollection". The error should list the line number that's causing the issue.

In this case, just the method name has changed.

```
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
```

This one it's just the method argument that needs to change.

```
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File)
```

I've encountered this one when using coverage, note in the following snippet the html.destination takes a raw string...

```
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
}
```

to remove the warning I changed it to to take a "File" object as follows:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/coverage")
    }
}
```

Comment: i just dont know about jacocoTestReport before, or just me who dont use it?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like in Gradle 7.x there is a new syntax. Instead of `html.destination` you should use `html.outputLocation`.

It should be something like:

```
html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('reports/coverage')
```